# Making my variable display the correct decimal place

Tags: java, average

I am doing a simple homework assignment and having a problem with my computation.
The answer to my calculator is 4.83, but my compiler says 4.00. How can correct this? 
Here is the part where I am having difficultly.

```
double test = 29/6;
 System.out.printf("%.2f",test);
 System.out.println(test);
```

Comment: this is really the most annoying thing about computers. everybody expects the default number to be a float and since it's an int, we have 1 question about this in stack overflow every day :-) [not a problem of who asks, IMO - it's really not intuitive.]

Comment: @Leo - I think it is because of optimality. Computing double is much slower than computing integer.

Comment: @libik I am pretty sure it's for performance reasons and I understand that. Still, I think this is annoying :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you divide two `integers` result is always `integer`

You have to cast one number from `int` to `double`.

```
 double test = (double)29/6;
 System.out.printf("%.2f",test);
 System.out.println(test);
```

Note that if you just write number, it is considered `int`

There is important thing, following code **prints 4.00 too** :

```
 double test = (double)(29/6);
 System.out.printf("%.2f",test);
 System.out.println(test);
```

Because first it divides two integers, therefore the result is also integer and then it is casted to double.

Using `(double)29/6` is same as `((double)29)/6`, because casting has higher priority.

Answer (score 1):

It's because both operands of division are `int`, therefore the whole result is truncated to type `int`. Make the operands `double` such as this and all works fine.

```
double test = 29.0/6.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's doing integer division, which truncates everything to the right of the decimal point , hence you are getting 4.

Try the below :

```
double test = 29.0/6;             
    System.out.printf("%.2f",test);
    System.out.println(test);
```

Output :

```
4.83
4.833333333333333
```